# Transform sql query to talend job

Tags: talend, tmap

I have this sql query that I would like to transform to a talend job. Been looking around but I'm not sure how this should be interpreted efficiently in talend. Below is the query:

```
SELECT p.DISPLAYNAME, T1.DESIGNTL, 
        p2.DISPLAYNAME, T1.DESIGNER,
        p3.DISPLAYNAME, T1.PERMITTL,
        p4.DISPLAYNAME, T1.SCHEDULER,
        p5.DISPLAYNAME, T1.SUPERVISOR
FROM  T1  
JOIN  PERSON p ON p.PERSONID = T1.DESIGNTL 
JOIN PERSON p2 ON p2.PERSONID = T1.DESIGNER
JOIN PERSON p3 ON p3.PERSONID = T1.PERMITTL
JOIN PERSON p4 ON p4.PERSONID = T1.SCHEDULER
JOIN PERSON p5 ON p5.PERSONID = T1.SUPERVISOR
```

How do I interpret the joins here. 1 main table and multiple instances of the 2nd table, using different columns of the 2nd table. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should isolate query each table. Use component that add prefix/suffix to column, then join with tMap ( 1 main table to tMap and other for lookup in tMap )

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I'm quite new to Talend, can you name the component that adds prefix/suffix to column?